# Flutter .. audioplayers package installation

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

i can not use either install the package

[image: Error Message]

[image: Flutter Doctor]

Answer (score 0):

Update the dependencies in pubspec.yaml
use `flutter pub upgrade`
also, attach the description of the place where it is used.

Comment: please .. read the error and description before answering!!